# How to assign a glob expression to a variable in a Bash script?

Tags: bash, glob

When the following two lines of code are executed in a bash script, "ls" complains that the files don't exist:

```
dirs=/content/{dev01,dev02}
ls -l $dirs
```

When I run the script with the -x option, it appears to be passing the variable within single quotes (which would prevent globbing):

```
+ dirs=/content/{dev01,dev01}
+ ls -l '/content/{dev01,dev01}'
ls: /content/{dev01,dev01}: No such file or directory
```

If I execute the "ls" command from my interactive shell (sans quotes), it returns the two directories.

I've been reading through the Bash Reference Manual (v 3.2) and can't see any reason for filename globbing to not take place (I'm not passing -f to the shell), or anything that I can set to ensure that globbing happens.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think it is the order of expansions:

> The order of expansions is: `brace
>   expansion`, tilde expansion, parameter,
>   `variable` and arithmetic expansion and
>   command substitution (done in a
>   left-to-right fashion), word
>   splitting, and `pathname expansion`.

So if your variable is substituted, brace expansion doesn't take place anymore. This works for me:

```
eval ls $dirs
```

Be very careful with eval. It will execute the stuff verbatimly. So if dirs contains `f{m,k}t*; some_command`, some_command will be executed after the ls finished. It will execute the string you give to `eval` in the current shell. It will pass `/content/dev01 /content/dev02` to ls, whether they exist or not. Putting `*` after the stuff makes it a pathname-expansion, and it will omit non-existing paths:

```
dirs=/content/{dev01,dev02}*
```

I'm not 100% sure about this, but it makes sense to me.

Comment: Brace expansion happens prior to variable expansion

Comment: yes, that is the reason. when the variable is expanded, brace expansion doesn't take place anymore, since it already took place before the variable was expanded.

Comment: if that were the case, I would have expected "dirs" to contain a list of words resulting from the brace expansion, which may or may not apply to the actual filesystem - but that doesn't appear to happen

Comment: pathname expansion will happen. so a=a* ls $a will expand to files starting with "a". but brace expansion won't happen.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb ls $a may expand to files starting with a but ls "$a" will not. The expansion did not happen in the assignment to a

Answer (score 34):

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20090403131119/http://www.mydatabasesupport.com/forums/shell/393265-bash-glob-expansion.html) is an excellent discussion of what you are trying to do.

The short answer is that you want an array:

```
dirs=(/content/{dev01,dev01})
```

But what you do with the results can get more complex than what you were aiming for I think.

Comment: I actually saw that thread, but it didn't seem to help me. The problem comes with the following "ls ${dirs}", which seems to get only the first entry in the array. I also tried "set ${dirs};ls $*" but that was the same result.

Comment: you have to do ls "${dirs[@]}" . but it will expand the names at assignment time to dirs. so dirs will actually contain the filenames, not only the pattern

Comment: The new link is dead

Comment: Link dead. Next time please quote the parts you are writing in relation to, it will be easier for everyone.

Answer (score 21):

For folks (like me) finding this through Google, @Peter and @feoh's answers are the general solution to "How to glob variables in bash script".

```
list_of_results=(pattern)
```

will save existing filenames matching `pattern` into the array `list_of_results`.  Each element of `list_of_results` will hold one filename, spaces and all.

You can  access each result as `"${list_of_results[<index>]}"` for `<index>` starting from 0.  You can get the entire list, properly quoted, as `"${list_of_results[@]}"`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer imho. Very clean.

Comment: One caveat with this solution is that if `pattern` doesn't match anything, the value of `list_of_results` is an array of one element, being `pattern` itself, instead of an empty array you might have expected...

Comment: @sxc731 use `shopt -s nullglob` to avoid this (see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126060/is-there-an-easy-way-to-set-nullglob-for-one-glob)

Answer (score 9):

This isn't filename globbing, this is brace expansion.
The difference is subtle, but it exists - in filename globbing you would only receive existing files as a result, while in brace expansion you can generate any kind of string.

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion

Now, this is what worked for me:

```
#!/bin/sh
dirs=`echo ./{dev01,dev02}`
ls $dirs
```

Comment: well then you could do  dirs=( ./{dev01,dev02} ); what feoh says. but it will expand at the time of the assignment. which may not what he want

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that what you need is an array, but that will restrict you to newer bashes.  It is saver than using eval.

```
dirs=( /"content with spaces"/{dev01,dev02} )

dirs=( /content/{dev01,dev02} )
ls -l "${dirs[@]}"
```

---

```
/content/{dev01,dev02}
```

will expand to:

```
"/content/dev01" "/content/dev02"
```

The existence of those directories is irrelevant to the expansion.

It becomes unpredictable when you assign a variable to a brace expansion.

```
dirs=/content/{dev01,dev02}
```

may turn into

```
"/content/dev01"
```

or

```
"/content/dev01 /content/dev02"
```

or

```
"/content/dev01" "/content/dev02"
```

or

```
"/content/{dev01,dev02}"
```

If you quote the braces in any way they will not expand, so the result will contain the braces and be mostly meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to glob *files,* you shouldn't use brace expansions. Using brace expansion in this case is an *antipattern* and definitely the wrong tool for the job.

What you want is [extended globbing](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching):

```
shopt -s extglob # likely already set in interactive shells

dirs=/content/@(dev01|dev02)
ls $dirs
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue which no-one has addressed is that the variable assignment makes the difference.

```
dirs=/content/{dev01,dev02}
```

expands differently than

```
echo /content/{dev01,dev02}
```

The question is how to assign the results of the expansion to `dirs`

See: [How to use Bash substitution in a variable declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700530/how-to-use-bash-substitution-in-a-variable-declaration#comment10833052_8700530)

Answer (score -2):

```
ls `echo $dirs`
```

works under cygwin.

Comment: Doesn't work in GNU bash, version 3.2.17(1)-release (i386-apple-darwin9.0)

Comment: It's 3.2.39(20) under cygwin.