# How to use Bash substitution in a variable declaration

Tags: bash

I try to declare a variable `x` with all chars from `a..x`. On the command line (bash), substitution of `a..x` works w/o any ticks.

```
$ echo {a..x}
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x
```

But assigning it to variable via `x={a..x}` results in `{a..x}` as string. Only `x=$(echo {a..x})` works.

The question is: Is this the proper way of assignment or do I have to do other things?

The main aim is to assign the sequence to an array, e.g.,

```
disks=( $(echo {a..x}) )
```

Comment: brace expansion fails on assignment because it produces a list and the variable only accepts a scalar value; bash is "smart" in this sense because it knows it can't assign a list to the variable so it doesn't expand it all, that's the same reason you can assign variables containing spaces without quoting them, since it's a scalar value bash doesn't apply word-splitting on the contents even when unquoted. the array however do accepts a list and in that case both brace expansion and word-splitting happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also use `set` (but be sure to save positional parameters if you still need them):

```
set {a..x}
x="$@"
```

For arrays, brace expansion works directly:

```
disks=( {a..x} )
```

Comment: `d=( {a..x} ) ; echo $d` on cmdline as well as in a script results in `a` only

Comment: @tuergeist, try `echo ${d[@]}` or `echo ${d[*]}` http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html

Comment: @akk: Thanks! Of course, just `d` points to the first element only.

Comment: @DominikDitoIvosevic: See `man bash`: > Referencing an array variable without a subscript is equivalent to referencing the array with a subscript of 0.