# How to use Bash substitution in a variable declaration 2

Tags: bash

[How to use Bash substitution in a variable declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700530/how-to-use-bash-substitution-in-a-variable-declaration)

Some of you may have read the aforementioned question but I have been left with more questions than answer. I tried googling how bash tokenizing -> expansion works in detail but did not find the right answers.

Let's look at simple example:

```
q="www"
e=$q{.,.,.}
echo $e 
#outputs: www{.,.,.}
```

Now this does not work as I would expect. Especially since `echo $q{.,.,.}` outputs `www. www. www.` as I would expect. There have been some sugestions in the first SO question to write stuff like `set $q{.,.,.,1} & s="$@" & echo $s`

This does work in the terminal but for some reasons when entered in a .sh script it outputs `www{.,.,.}`

Why is there a different behaviour between the script and the terminal and  how to make sure to trigger the expansion?

Also, why does `q=*` trigger pathname expansion but `q={.,.,.}` does not trigger braces expansion?

Comment: Aw man I was running the script with sh and not bash :/

Comment: That doesn't matter, though. Brace expansions do not occur on the right-hand side of an assignment statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bash performs expansion [in a defined order](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions), and brace expansion happens *before* parameter expansion.

When bash sees `echo $e`, there are no brace expansions to perform. After the parameter expansion, bash does not go back to the prior ones.

If you need this, you can do one of:

```
e=$(echo $q{.,.,.}); echo "$e"

e=$q{.,.,.}; eval echo "$e"
```

Answer (score 2):

### Scalars Aren't Arrays

To do what you want, you need to assign *e* as an array. You can then use [array expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to view the contents in the way you expect. Consider the following:

```
q="www"
e=( $q{.,.,.} )
echo "${e[@]}"
```

> www. www. www.

Comment: Not quite. `e` is assigned the entire value, but that value isn't subject to brace expansion. `$q{.,.,.}` simply expands to the literal string `www{.,.,.}`. In the array assignment, brace expansion does occur, to `$q. $q. $q.`, prior to parameter expansion which expands each occurrence of `$q`.

Answer (score 1):

Words in the right-side of an assignment do not: "Brace Expand"

From "man bash" (emphasis mine):

> A variable may be assigned to by a statement of the form
>
> ```
>          name=[value]
> ```
>
> All values undergo **tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal**

There is no mention of "Brace Expansion", "Pathname expansion" or "splitting".

To get "Brace expansion" make it a command line (note that `"$q"` is quoted):

```
$ q="www"
$ e="$( echo "$q"{.,.,.} )"
$ echo "$e" 
www. www. www.
```

Or if you want an array (s asked in the linked question), use directly:

```
$ e=( "$q"{.,.,.} )
$ printf '<%s> ' "${e[@]}"; echo         ### No, `$e` is not enough.
<www.> <www.> <www.>
```

> why does q=* trigger pathname expansion

No, it doesn't:

```
$ a=* ; echo "$a"
*
```

Of course, an unquoted `$a` will undergo pathname expansion, try:

```
$ a=* ; echo $a
```