# Is there an easy way to set nullglob for one glob

Tags: bash, glob, shopt

In bash, if you do this:

```
mkdir /tmp/empty
array=(/tmp/empty/*)
```

you find that `array` now has one element, `"/tmp/empty/*"`, not zero as you'd like. Thankfully, this can be avoided by turning on the nullglob shell option using `shopt -s nullglob`

But nullglob is global, and when editing an existing shell script, may break things (e.g., did someone check the exit code of `ls foo*` to check if there are files named starting with "foo"?). So, ideally, I'd like to turn it on only for a small scope—ideally, one filename expansion. You can turn it off again using `shopt -u nullglob` But of course only if it was disabled before:

```
old_nullglob=$(shopt -p | grep 'nullglob$')
shopt -s nullglob
array=(/tmp/empty/*)
eval "$old_nullglob"
unset -v old_nullglob
```

makes me think there must be a better way. The obvious "put it in a subshell" doesn't work as of course the variable assignment dies with the subshell. Other than [waiting for the Austin group](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=247#bugnotes) to import ksh93 syntax, is there?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With `mapfile` in Bash 4, you can load an array from a subshell with something like: `mapfile array < <(shopt -s nullglob; for f in ./*; do echo "$f"; done)`. Full example:

```
$ shopt nullglob
nullglob        off
$ find
.
./bar baz
./qux quux
$ mapfile array < <(shopt -s nullglob; for f in ./*; do echo "$f"; done)
$ shopt nullglob
nullglob        off
$ echo ${#array[@]}
2
$ echo ${array[0]}
bar baz
$ echo ${array[1]}
qux quux
$ rm *
$ mapfile array < <(shopt -s nullglob; for f in ./*; do echo "$f"; done)
$ echo ${#array[@]}
0
```

- Be sure to glob with `./*` instead of a bare `*` when using `echo` to print the file name
- Doesn't work with newline characters in the filename :( as pointed out by *derobert*

---

If you need to handle newlines in the filename, you will have to do the much more verbose:

```
array=()
while read -r -d $'\0'; do
    array+=("$REPLY")
done < <(shopt -s nullglob; for f in ./*; do printf "$f\0"; done)
```

But by this point, it may be simpler to follow the advice of one of the other answers.

Comment: This is pretty good. It will fail if filenames have newlines in them, but although that's allowed, it's pretty rare. As long as file names aren't under an attacker's control.

Comment: Yes, newlines in filenames do exist. Normally, that should only mean "find the culprit and punish him/her". Except that the only time I saw newlines in file names, the culprit was a charming elder lady...

Comment: This solution keeps inserting newlines at the end of file names that don't originally contain one. If you use `mapfile -t` it will strip off a newline at the end of the filename if it exists.

Answer (score 18):

Unset it when done:

```
shopt -u nullglob
```

And properly (i.e. storing the previous state):

```
shopt -u | grep -q nullglob && changed=true && shopt -s nullglob
... do whatever you want ...
[ $changed ] && shopt -u nullglob; unset changed
```

Comment: That does avoid the eval, and I didn't realize -s and -u had that behavior (`help shopt` fails to mention it). I'm upvoting it for those. But honestly, its not really simpler—in terms of what you have to remember to get right, there is a lot in that first line.

Comment: I never said it was simpler :-) But it just do what your question asked, use nullglob without affecting other scripts started from the same session. Remembering the value of nullglob adds complexity, but it's the only way you can _preserve_ the environment as it was.

Comment: Well, the question was for a *better* or *easier* way to do it (as the second code example in the question also manages to restore the setting back to its previous state). Apparently, I didn't make that clear in the question—please suggest how to improve it.

Comment: I don't think you can improve that. The amount of code being called is minimal. Indeed you said an "easier" way, but your example is not doing what you wanted, i.e. not cluttering the rest of the code with your changes to nullglob. Sorry if this is not the answer you were expecting, perhaps somebody else can answer it better. Don't despair ;-)

Answer (score 8):

This is just a tiny bit better than your original suggestion:

```
local nullglob=$(shopt -p nullglob) ; shopt -s nullglob
```

... do whatever you want ...

```
$nullglob ; unset nullglob
```

Comment: I think you meant:
$nullglob # unset nullglob

Answer (score 2):

This may be close to what you want; as is, it requires executing a command to expand the glob.

```
$ ls
file1 file2
$ array=( $(shopt -s nullglob; ls foo*) )
$ ls foo*
ls: foo*: No such file or directory
$ echo ${array[*]}
file1 file2
```

Instead of setting `array` in the subshell, we create a subshell using `$()` whose output is captured by `array`.

Comment: Doesn't work with spaces (no surprise): `touch "file1" "file 2"; array=( $(shopt -s nullglob; ls foo*) ); set | grep ^array` produces `array=([0]="file1" [1]="file" [2]="2")`

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest solution I've found:

For example, to expand the literal `**/*.mp3` into a glob for only a particular variable, you can use

```
VAR=**/*.mp3(N)
```

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/204944/56160

Comment: Note that is a zsh feature not found in bash, which OP specified.