# Test whether a glob has only one match in bash and get it

Tags: bash, glob

The question ["Test whether a glob has any matches in bash"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937407/test-whether-a-glob-has-any-matches-in-bash) and it's answer is quite well.

But, I want to know how to test whether a glob has **only one** match in bash and if it exists assign to a variable.

How can I do it?

Comment: What are you attempting to match with a glob of `'*'`? Files, a list of something else? Like `cnt=0; for i in *; do myvar="$i"; ((cnt++)); done; [ "$cnt" -ne 1 ] && unset myvar`? Then you can simply test `[ -n "$myvar" ] && echo "only match was '$myvar'"`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin In this solution, if the glob matches nothing, it will simply have one result that equals to the glob. Hot to solve it?

Comment: Good catch. `[ "$cnt" -eq 0 ] || [ "$cnt" -ne 1 ] && unset myvar` (see edit)

Comment: What is your glob expression? It is just `*` or do you have a specific expression

Comment: More possibilities are specific expressions. What is the difference between `*` or a specific expression? @Inian

Comment: No, "$cnt" can't be 0

Comment: Can you show us a specific example of what your glob is and what you would like to check. For now, your question is unclear

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need `nullglob`. With a simple test you can validate if your glob expanded to a single entry, or zero or more entries:

```
globexpand=( globexpression )
[[ -e "${globexpand[@]}" ]] && var="$globexpand"
```

This works for the following reasons:

1. if `globexpression` matches multiple files, the test with `-e` will fail
2. if `globexpression` matches a single file, the test with `-e` will match
3. if `globexpression` matches no file, the `globexpand` will hold the `globexpression` as a single entry and will fail the test with `-e`.

So you do not need any `nullglob` or any special option. Just make sure you quote correctly here to handle filenames with *special* characters.

An alternative way is to make use of `find` to count how many matches your glob has:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -name 'globexpr' -printf c | wc -c
```

We make use of `printf` so that we do not have a problem with funny filenames which might contain a newline character. Having this said, it is now straightforward:

```
if [[ $(find . -maxdepth 1 -name 'globexpr' -printf c | wc -c) == "1" ]]; then
    # do your magic
else
    # do some other stuff
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set `nullglob` to expand globs to nothing if they match nothing. That will solve the problem the glob hanging around if there are no files matching it.

For example, here's a function which sets nullglob only for the function:

```
set_one () {
    # Usage:
    #    set_one myvar "some?glob*"

    # save nullglob setting (https://stackoverflow.com/a/34957289/2072269),
    # disable field splitting and enable nullgob
    declare nullglob=$(shopt -p nullglob) IFS=
    shopt -s nullglob

    # expand second argument as a glob and reset nullglob to saved setting
    declare -a array=($2) 
    eval "$nullglob"

    (( ${#array[@]} != 1 )) && return 1

    # save first element of array to variable given by first argument
    printf -v "$1" "%s" "$array"
}
```

Example:

```
$ ls
a  b  c
$ set_one foo "*"; echo $? "$foo"
1
$ set_one foo "a*"; echo $? "$foo"
0 a
$ set_one foo "[d]"; echo $? "$foo"
1 a  # retains previous value
```