# create tar file from some .tar.gz file

Tags: shell, tar

I would like to create a `.tar` file from all `.gz` files in `$a/$b` and delete those files afterwards.

I have come up with the following code but it's not working:

```
cd "$a"
#tar cf $a/$b'.tar' "$b_sql.gz" "$b_moh.tar.gz" 
tar cf $a/$b'.tar' $b'_*.gz'
gzip $a/$b'.tar'
rm -f $b'_*.gz'
```

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70243/farsi-programming-discussion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I try this way and answer :

```
cd "$a"
for f in $b'_*.gz'
do
   tar cf $a/$b'.tar' $f
done
```

Comment: Namordim o ye irani didim inja

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your use of `*` within a string. It's treating `*` as a character rather than doing the glob in the shell.

You can test this yourself by running `ls *.gz` and then `ls '*.gz'` within your shell.

Comment: So what should I do for this?

Comment: Probably best covered in this stack overflow answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369145/how-to-glob-variables-in-bash-script